# iphone: How to add current project files o SVN?

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, repository, xcode4.2

I have developed a part of application now I want to add my project to SVN repository for that 
i did

File->Source Control->Repositories

Add Repositories

Added repository sccessfully, but when in project root I right clicked to add project to repository it showed all disable option of source control.

How can I add my project to SVN repository, please help

[image]

while repository is added

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would you not just place all of your files into your trunk manually and open the project from there, and then set up your repository in Organiser. The files would all already be there, and then you can right click on the file you have changed and commit it from there.

I also like to use public repositories such as [Google Code](http://code.google.com) to store my repositories, which is especially helpful in case of data issues when working with lots of people on the one SVN project.